# Replace values in one column based on condition using its name as a string

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c1=1:6, c2=2:7)
```

I can happily replace values in `c2` that are larger then `4` doing

```
df$c2[df$c2 > 4] <- 10
```

yielding the desired output

```
  c1 c2
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
4  4 10
5  5 10
6  6 10
```

However, I want to select the column by its name using a string, in this case `"c2"`, as the column selection should not be hard-coded but it is context dependent.

The best I could come up with is

```
df[,c('c2')][df[,c('c2')] > 4] <- 1000
```

yielding

```
  c1   c2
1  1    2
2  2    3
3  3    4
4  4 1000
5  5 1000
6  6 1000
```

It works, but I find it rather ugly. Is there a better way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using `replace`

```
df['c2'] <- replace(df['c2'], df['c2'] > 4, 100)
df

#  c1  c2
#1  1   2
#2  2   3
#3  3   4
#4  4 100
#5  5 100
#6  6 100
```

Or something similar as your attempt

```
df['c2'][df['c2'] > 4] <- 100
```

Comment: @Cleb just realized no need of `[[`, single `[` works too.

Comment: Why the chaining of `[]`? `df[df['c2'] > 4, 'c2'] <- 100` should do it right?

Comment: @thelatemail: Indeed, that's then the best solution, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If one is open to packages, we can use `purrr`'s `modify_at` or `dplyr`'s `mutate_at`

```
purrr::modify_at(df,"c2",
                 function(x) 
                   ifelse(x>4,100,x))
```

With `dplyr`:

```
mutate_at(df,"c2",
                 function(x) 
                   ifelse(x>4,100,x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `transform` and `ifelse`

```
transform(df, c2 = ifelse(c2 > 4, 100, c2))
#  c1  c2
#1  1   2
#2  2   3
#3  3   4
#4  4 100
#5  5 100
#6  6 100
```

---

If we need to pass a string, one option with `dplyr`, would be convert to symbol and evaluate

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(!! "c2" := replace(!! rlang::sym("c2"), 
           !! rlang::sym("c2")  > 4, 100))
#  c1  c2
#1  1   2
#2  2   3
#3  3   4
#4  4 100
#5  5 100
#6  6 100
```

Comment: I need `c2` as a string. When I try `transform(df, 'c2' = ifelse('c2' > 4, 1000, 'c2'))`, then all values in `c2` are updated to `1000`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cleb It is not evaluated.  You need to convert to symbol like the `dplyr` ssolution updated

Comment: @Cleb  I also see solutions here without the quoted form.  That is the reason I posted that answer

Comment: Ah, don't get me wrong, happy about each answer, not an expert in R at all, so happy to learn. Was just wondering whether there is a straightforward way to accomplish that...

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df$c2 > 4, 'c2'] <- 10
# or
df$c2 <- with(df, replace(c2, c2 > 4, 10))
```

Using package `data.table` you could do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[c2 > 4, c2 := 10]
```

Comment: This still has the `df$c2` in it which I would like to avoid.

Comment: The datatable version works fine, but comes at the costs of converting it back to a dataframe.

Comment: @Cleb `$x` is just a shorthand for `[["x"]]`. You can convert back to `setDF()`.